# How to use plugins like vue-resource when using Vue.js with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-resource

I started using Typescript and trying to apply it to my project. However, I can't get Vue.js plugins like vue-resource to work with it.

When I use

```
this.$http.post()
```

I get the error:

> error TS2339: Property '$http' does not exist on type 'typeof Vue'.

which makes sense because I am in a class context. But how can I do that? This is my full component:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Sign up</h1>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input v-model="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Please provide a name.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Password</label>
      <input v-model="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Please provide a password.</small>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" @click.prevent="save">
  </form>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class SignUp extends Vue {
  name: string = ''
  password: string = ''

  save(): void {
    this.$http.post('/api/sign-up', {
        name: this.name,
        password: this.password
      })
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

And I register vue-resource in my `main.ts` like this:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import router from "./router"
import App from "./app"

const VueResource = require('vue-resource')

Vue.use(VueResource)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  template: "<App/>",
  components: { App },
});
```

Comment: What happens if you import VueResource using the `import` statement and not `require`? I don't use typescript, but `$http` is undefined, in js, when using `require`; `import` works fine.

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thank you so much. I had to `require` it because of some older errors but now it seems to work. You may convert your comment into an answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `import` instead of `require` for VueResource too.

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
```

Comment: `node_modules/vue-resource/t...' is not assignable to type 'PluginFunction<any>'.` and `node_modules/vue-resource/t...' provides no match for the signature '(Vue: VueConstructor<Vue>, options?: any): void'.[39m`

Comment: i am also getting  this issue :

Argument of type 'Promise<{ default: typeof "D:/Workshop/nodejs/ef-web-components/node_modules/vue-resource/types/i
...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ default: typeof ' is not assig
nable to type 'PluginFunction<any>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ default: typeof ' provides n
o match for the signature '(Vue: VueConstructor<Vue>, options?: any): void'